# Hadoop: Split metadata size exceeded 10000000

Tags: hadoop, cascading

When I ran a cascading job, I get an error:

```
Split metadata size exceeded 10000000
```

I try to increase the limit on a per job level by passing the following to commandline

```
xxx.jar -D mapreduce.job​.split.metainfo.maxsi‌​ze=30000000
```

I also tried

```
xxx.jar -D mapreduce.jobtracker​.split.metainfo.maxsi‌​ze=30000000
```

But both doesn't work, I still get the same error, so the argument is not picked. I am using hadoop 2.5. Anyone can point out what I did wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Can you try setting following property in `conf/mapred-site.xml`:

```
<!-- No limits if set to -1 -->
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.jobtracker.split.metainfo.maxsize</name>
    <value>-1</value>
</property>
```

Not sure if following will help (give it a shot)

```
xxx.jar -D mapreduce.jobtracker​.split.metainfo.maxsi‌​ze=-1
```

Reference: https://archive.cloudera.com/cdh/3/hadoop/mapred-default.html

```
| Name                                        | Default Value | Description                                                                                                                                                                                                                   |
|---------------------------------------------|---------------|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| mapred.jobtracker.job.history.block.size    | 3145728       | The block size of the job history file. Since the job recovery uses job,history, its important to dump job history to disk as soon as possible.,Note that this is an expert level parameter. The default value is set to,3 MB |
| mapreduce.jobtracker.split.metainfo.maxsize | 10000000      | The maximum permissible size of the split metainfo file. The JobTracker,won't attempt to read split metainfo files bigger than the configured,value. No limits if set to -1.                                                  |
```

Comment: I don't have the permission to set the mapred file, on the per job level, i tried that but still doesn't work